# SQL query error with too many parameters in "in" clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query below:

```
Select t1.[Column1]
From [dbo].[Table1]
Where(
    t1.[Column2] = @parameter0
AND
    t1.[Column3] IN (@parameter1, @parameter2, @parameter3...............)
```

and I have parameters up to `@parameter1390`.

C# application that is using this SQL query reports

> *An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to simplify them.*

What can I do to optimize my query?

Comment: Where do these many parameters come from?

Comment: Put the values into a table and then do a join on the table.  In addition to better performance, it will be much more scalable.

Comment: Since it's in C#, run a single parameter at a time in a loop and add the values to a variable.

Comment: Yeah look at using table valued parameters instead of 1300+ individual parameters. And why do have so many parameters? Seems there ought to be a much simpler way of doing whatever it is you are doing.

Comment: So your question is related to do with c# and not SQL.

Comment: Another (less optimal) solution is to split the long `IN` into several `IN`s `OR`ed together. However, putting it in a table is better.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, No it's not a duplicate. OP is not trying to limit that `IN` in SQL cause would have it been SQL then we probably don't need to restrict. OP rather, trying to pass that IN clause from C# where facing the issue.

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestions. I will try @Hambone's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As you can use a temp table in order to keep your values, You can use union operator to reach goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this cosmetic changes in your code

```
Select t1.[Column1]
From [dbo].[Table1]
Where(
    t1.[Column2] = @parameter0
AND
    t1.[Column3] IN 
(select a from (values(@parameter1), (@parameter2), (@parameter3),...) x(a))
```